# how to draw a certain shape and place it next to a text inside a textbox in wpf

Tags: wpf

I want used polygone to draw a form inside a button and then put it inside a stackpanel with a text but the result is deceiving...

this is my code:

```
<Button x:Name="button2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="75">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Canvas>
                    <Polygon
                        Points="0,-10 16,-10 20,-6 20,10 0,10 0,-10"
                        Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="1"
                        Fill="#4C87B3"/>
                    <Polygon
                        Points="2,-10 14,-10 14,-3 2,-3 2,-10"
                        Stroke="#d6d6c2"
                        StrokeThickness="1"
                        Fill="#d6d6c2"/>
                    <Polygon
                        Points="4,-9 6,-9 6,-4 4,-4 4,-9"
                        Stroke="#4C87B3"
                        StrokeThickness="1"
                        Fill="#4C87B3"/>
                </Canvas>
                <TextBlock Text="Save" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
```

the result:

[image]

and then in adition to that i want to give this figure some effect like the shadow shown in this picture below:

[image]

Comment: Besides that the Grid is redundant, you probably just want to set the Canvas Width and Height and compensate for the negative coordinates with a Margin.

Comment: An icon like this may perhaps better be created as a DrawingImage, and used with an Image element. It would then easily be replaceable by a bitmap, i.e. a BitmapImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want to stack the `Polygon` elements on top of each other, it is sufficient to add them to a `Grid`. When wrap this `Grid` into a `Viewbox`, the icon will automatically scale, when setting e.g. `Viewbox.Width`. To prevent the icon from overlapping due to its negative positions, you have to add some `Margin` to the `Grid` that hosts the shapes.

To add a drop shadow simply add a `DropShadowEffect` to the outer `Polygon.Effect`.

```
<Button x:Name="button2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="75"
        Height="30">
  <StackPanel>
    <Viewbox Width="12" Stretch="Uniform">
      <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <Polygon
          Points="0,-10 16,-10 20,-6 20,10 0,10 0,-10"
          Stroke="Black"
          StrokeThickness="1"
          Fill="#4C87B3">
          <Polygon.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.9" 
                              ShadowDepth="5"  
                              Direction="315" 
                              Color="Black" 
                              BlurRadius="10" />
          </Polygon.Effect>
        </Polygon>
        <Polygon
          Points="2,-10 14,-10 14,-3 2,-3 2,-10"
          Stroke="#d6d6c2"
          StrokeThickness="1"
          Fill="#d6d6c2" />
        <Polygon
          Points="4,-9 6,-9 6,-4 4,-4 4,-9"
          Stroke="#4C87B3"
          StrokeThickness="1"
          Fill="#4C87B3" />
      </Grid>
    </Viewbox>

    <TextBlock Text="Save" FontSize="12" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```